# Google Developer Console project creation limit

Tags: android, google-api-console

I'm just trying to establish what the limitation is on creating new Projects within the current Google Developer Console. We've hit a vague quota limit message at 28 Projects.

We've had discussions previously about whether we need to.. our apps use GCM, Maps, Places API and a few other services, and, as per the help section, we're not creating separate Projects to bypass individual API limits - each app is an individual entity.

On the old API Console the help stated *"You can create **as many projects as you need**, but please remember that you cannot use multiple projects to try to exceed the limits for API usage"*

In the new Developer Console the corresponding phrase is *"You can create **multiple projects**, but remember..."* ...almost the same, but "multiple" is not "as many as you need" and implies a limit that I can't find.

Anyone know what the limit is, if it's just a timed restriction (ie. a number per day), if it's pay-to-extend-able etc?

Comment: I suspect Google may be purposefully vague on this. There is probably also language that points out it is there sole discretion what is too many.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a Google service policy question.