# Google Developers Console project creation quota

Tags: android, google-api, google-cloud-platform, quota, google-api-console

I have created a total of 30 projects in the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/project), including 23 between 12/23 and 12/27. Most recently, 3 projects were created on 12/27. When I tried to create a 4th project on 12/27, I got the message `You have exceeded the quota for project creations per day.` It has now been well over 24 hours since then, and I still cannot add new projects.

This same question has gone unanswered (at least) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25286612/google-developer-console-project-creation-limit), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27221130/you-have-exceeded-the-quota-for-project-creations-per-day-it-drive-me-crazy) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26492217/projects-quota-for-google-developers-console).

Is it possible that nobody actually knows what the quota is? Since I have waited more than 24 hours after receiving the message before adding any new projects, and only 3 were added in the 24 hour period prior to that, it would appear that I have triggered something that has longer lasting impact, and isn't just a limit for the current day.

I can live with a ~20 per day limit, but not with a maximum of ~30 projects. Is there another account type I need to have with Google? Does anyone have experience in getting past this or in contacting Google directly for assistance?

Comment: Same here, hit the limit on 25.12, being blocked until now . You could try to create a second account as quick solution

Comment: I'm reasonably confident that this will work, but the immediate needs of our company will require that we open 20 or more additional accounts, then we have to keep track of which apps are under what account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may not be helpful to everyone with this problem, but here's what worked for our needs...

We were creating new projects in the Developers Console for each app so that each would have its own unique sender key for push notifications. What we discovered is that all apps can have the same sender key, as long as the push notification server (AWS SNS in our case) can differentiate the delivery targets by another means, which we're doing by bundle ID when devices register for push. In the end, we didn't need to have unique projects for each app.

It doesn't answer the questions of what the limits are or how to get past them once they've been reached, but it provided the means to the end we were seeking.

Answer (score 7):

So I did ran in to this a few months ago. At that time I did not see a solution. Though when I tried again today that error notice have been updated with a link to a form where you can request a increase of the project quota for your account. This is likely a ongoing roll out at the moment (I don't get this in all my accounts).

Reference it looks like this:[image]

You may not see this updated message yet. Any how, the form link is https://support.google.com/code/contact/project_quota_increase. After filling in the form support got in touch pretty much within a day and my quota is now raised.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Good to know.

Comment: I have no project on cloud console (i have deleted all) but still it showing the same to raise quota limit

Comment: Does it take money to increase the quota of project?