# Google Developers: You have exceeded the maximum number of projects that you can create

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, onesignal, google-developers-console

I have ten Android apps that support Push Notification with [OneSignal](https://onesignal.com).

I always followed this manual: [OneSignal manual: Generate Google Server API Key](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/generate-a-google-server-api-key).

I always created a new project as in the manual described.

Now I wanted an eleventh app to be able to get Push Notifications. But when following the manual I'm getting:

> You have exceeded the maximum number of projects that you can create.
>   Try deleting a few projects in the Google Developers Console.

at [Add Project in Google Developer Console](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=gcm).

What can I do? Won't I able to make more apps be able to receive Push Notifications?

I hope anybody can help me because it's a time-sensitive project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Developers Console project creation quota](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27676900/google-developers-console-project-creation-quota)

Comment: I overcame from the error by deleting my some of the unuseful project from google-developers-console.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any unuseful projects. Any other idea?

Comment: I made a request here (https://support.google.com/code/contact/project_quota_increase) ca. 30 minutes before and just got this e-mail:  `Dear Developer,
We have approved your request for additional quota for non-paid Cloud Services. Your new quota should take effect within one hour of receiving this message.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can re-use the same project number and server key across multiple android apps without any issues. This is the best way to support notifications for more than 10 apps.

Comment: Are you sure this'll work for OneSignal Push notifications?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a request here: [support.google.com/code/contact/project_quota_increase](http://support.google.com/code/contact/project_quota_increase)

I got a positive Quota Granted-response within 30 minutes although I'm not using any paid services.